# pandas returning header instead of values

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a list of a sliding window from a pandas dataframe but instead of giving me the specific values it only returns the header. Why is this happening and what can I do to get around this?

```
import pandas as pd

batch_size = 3
data = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])


def process(data):
    batches = []
    for i in range(len(data) - batch_size + 1):
        batches.append(list(data.iloc[i:i + batch_size]))

    return batches

process(data)
```

Comment: I ran your code and got `[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]`. Doesn't look like headers to me.

Comment: it is its just because that data doesn't have a header so it automatically makes the header 0. There is no 0 in the data

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]...[7,8,9]]

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a list comprehension instead of a for loop:

```
[data.iloc[i:i + batch_size, 0].tolist() 
     for i in range(data.shape[0] - batch_size + 1)]
#[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.iloc` instead of `pd.DataFrame.iloc` to produce rolling values for a series:

```
data[0].iloc[i:(i+batch_size)]

# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Your result is because you are effectively calculating `list` of a dataframe for specified index range, which is not clear. `list(data)`, for example, returns `[0]`, and it's not obvious what you should *expect* from such code.